# Azure portal - cannot create a DevOps resource

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I attempt to create a new DevOps resource using the Azure portal. The React-style spinner just sticks, as if busy. If I recall correctly I should see a list of project "types" to select from? I never get to that.

How do I fix that?

Also, possibly related, how do I import or otherwise "make visible" code I have stored at `dev.azure.com` from way before I first signed in to Azure? Same Microsoft creds at each site. The `DevOps` account was originally created with Visual Studio Community Edition though I normally just git from a shell.

Comment: you dont really create azure devops from azure portal. can you share a screenshot or explain what are you doing exactly?

Comment: Microsoft Azure -> Create a resource -> DevOps Project -> stalls...
https://imgur.com/a/zkpOPk6 - the pane on the right loads after clicking "Create a resource"

Comment: interesting, i thought you can only link that. it definitely works for me. can you try incognito mode\another browser\another pc\virtual machine?

Comment: Interesting. I fired up azure in Firefox in a reasonably vanilla Ubuntu VM and it seems to work fine. I was then able to "bring my own code" from dev.azure using my login creds. I guess I expected to be able to simply "link" it into my azure portal somehow, but Azure isn't really about dev work, it's about running applications and services...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in this case the problem went away by using browser on another computer

Comment: Looks like something to do with the Chrome cache on Win10. FF on Win10 now lets me in...